# Validate pk as int in drf viewset retrieve url

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, drf-extensions

Code looks as follows:

```
class UserViewSet(ViewSet):

    # ... Many other actions
    def list(self):
        # list implementation

    def retrieve(self, request, pk):
        # manual pk int validation

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r"users", UserViewSet, basename="users")
urlpatterns = router.urls
```

Right now pk is not validated as int therefore a request to db is made, which I want to avoid. Is there any way I can add that type of validation in urls?
I can achieve that without using router like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('users/<int:pk>/', UserViewSet.as_view({'get': 'retrieve'}),
    # many other actions have to be added seperately
]
```

But I have many actions in my viewset and all of them have to be added separately. Is there a cleaner way to do so or a package?

Comment: What you mean by "*pk is not validated as int*"?  the **`\d+`** will only match with integers, won't it?

Comment: That's my workaround. When I use router it allows non digits to pass.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use **`lookup_value_regex`** attribute as,

```
class UserViewSet(ViewSet):
    lookup_value_regex = '\d+'
    ...
```